# Compiling dilemma(code blocks and ubuntu)

Tags: c, ubuntu, compilation, ubuntu-14.04, codeblocks

I have this project I'm working on, and after a week of coding, I finally completed it. I created the program (compiled it) using Code::Blocks (I'm using only Windows 7). It runs perfectly.

However, if I transfer the same c-file to a virtualbox(ubuntu), when I compile it, there were no errors, but the way the program runs is different.

In my program there are numerous functions for input restrictions. In my virtual box, I can't seem to pass through the first restriction. I have yet to discover if my I will not be able to get through the next restrictions.

for example:

```
    while(1){
    printf("Enter the number of rows:");
    fgets(rows, 100, stdin);
    string_clean(rows); // '\n' to '\0'
    c=numstring_check(rows, strlen(rows));


    if(c==0){
        printf("INVALID!\n");
    }else if(c!=0){
        rows_i=strtol(rows, &remain, 10);
        if ((rows_i>10 || rows_i<1)){
            printf("INVALID!\n");
            continue;
        }else
            break;
    }
    }
```

numstring function is:

```
int numstring_check (char array[], int size) {
int i,j,flag=0;
for (i=0; i<size; i++){
    j=isdigit(array[i]);
    if(j!=1){
        flag=1;
        break;
    }
}
if (flag==1)
    return 0;
}
```

This is only one problem. My dilemma is, I have multiple functions that run through this function and this isn't my only input checker.

If this block of code is run through codeblocks, it works fine, but on ubuntu, it just prints "Invalid" whatever input I encode. I need serious help.

Comment: basically, it checks if the input string consists of digits only. After that, since I'm sure it's in digits, I convert it using strtol, and send it to another if statement to check if it's anything between 1 and 10, I store it in a variable. If not, it should rempropt the user to input a correct value until a correct input is read.

Comment: [isdigit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) return Non-zero value if the character is a numeric character, zero otherwise.

Comment: Add `return 1;` at the end of `numstring_check` function.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans, please indent consistently.  I.E. indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Never use tabs for indenting.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts and allows for many indent levels across the page

Answer (score 0):

the function: `isdigit()` returns a NON_ZERO when the parameter is a digit.

That does not mean that it will return 1. Suggest using:

```
if( !j )
```

as your test for a non digit. A better plan would be to eliminate j so the call to `isdigit()` and the `if()` are combined into:

```
if( !isdigit(array[i]) )
```